# Prove that $|a|+|b|\le \sqrt{2}|z|$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I was solving maths and got struk on this question.might you help me with this one.

If z=a+ib Then, prove that

$|a|+|b|\le \sqrt{2}|z|$

I don't know how to start it.

Help me.

Comment: Use the fact that $(a-b)^2\ge 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $$\frac{x+y}{2}\le\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} $ so the inequality is equivalent (taking the square)
$$(|a|+|b|)^2\le 2(a^2+b^2)\iff 0\le a^2+b^2-2|ab|=(|a|-|b|)^2$$
which is true.

Comment: Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

By convexity, $$\sqrt 2|z|=\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2}=\sqrt{\frac{4a^2+4b^2}{2}}\ge \frac{\sqrt{4a^2}+\sqrt{4b^2}}{2}=|a|+|b|$$

Comment: you are so smart

Comment: @ShivamGautam As are you! Cheers